# How to search in a queue?

Tags: c, search, data-structures, queue

Suppose if I enter 5 passenger's details I'm only able to retrieve the first passenger's details even if I search for the 4th passenger's details.I need to find any element in the list.If current= frontq; it's showing first element when searched.

CODE:

```
int search()
{   struct bag *next;

    char *n,*f;


    current=frontq;
    printf("Enter name to be searched:\n");
    scanf("%s",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the  flight number\n");
    scanf("%s",&f);
    while((current->name==n)&&(current->fl_no==f))
    {
    current=current->next;
    next++;
    }
     printf ("\n The Searched luggage is\n");
    printf("%s\n",current->name);
    printf("%s\n",current->dest);
    printf("%s\n",current->fl_no);
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. For things like lists, it also helps to use pen and paper to draw the list and the pointers and operations you do.

Comment: 'current->name==n'.....Google or man 'strcmp'.

Comment: And it seems you were asleep when your teacher taught `scanf` and how to use it. Or you simply skipped the very early chapters of your beginners book or tutorial.

Comment: 'I'm only able to retrieve the first passenger's details'...I suspect that your list is borked anyway, though it may be some artifact of the scanf/pointer UB noted by @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what queue structure contains but assuming some things ....

You are comparing name pointers rather than the content of the name `current->name==n` - use the strcmp function.

In addition, scanf is reading a prompted for name to the memory references by n, which is unassigned - you need to declare a buffer:

`char n[100];`

And scanf should be `scanf("%s",n);` not `scanf("%s",&n);`

Comment: Thanks! It definitely helped me!

Answer (score 0):

For starters these pointers

```
char *n,*f;
```

are not initialized and have indeterminate values.

And these calls of scanf

```
scanf("%s",&n);
scanf("%s",&f);
```

use incorrect arguments and as a result invoke undefined behavior.

You need to declare arrays of appropriate sizes as for example

```
char n[N], f[N];
```

where N is some values and at least in calls of scanf to write

```
scanf( "%s", n);
scanf( "%s", f);
```

Also in the condition of the while loop that is written incorrectly comparing pointers

```
while((current->name==n)&&(current->fl_no==f))
```

you should write

```
while( current != NULL && 
       !( strcmp( current->name, n ) == 0 && strcmp( current->fl_no, f ) == 0 ) )
```

And after the loop you should write

```
if ( current != NULL )
{
    printf ("\n The Searched luggage is\n");
    printf("%s\n",current->name);
    printf("%s\n",current->dest);
    printf("%s\n",current->fl_no);
}
```

Also the return value of the function does not make a sense. It is better to write the return expression like

```
return current != NULL;
```

In this case the user of the function can check whether the required element of the queue was found or not.

Comment: Thanks! It definitely helped me!